# How to change ID-s order in mysql table (resort records by values)

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-order-by, where-clause

MySql table has 2 fields: `id`,`value`.

For example, I have array with values:

```
$arr = ['BMW','Audi','Opel'...]
```

I need to change records ID-s in order of values in array.

**For example:**

Before:

```
id  value
12, 'Audi'
18, 'BMW'
32, 'Opel'
```

After:

```
id  value
18, 'Audi'
12, 'BMW'
32, 'Opel'
```

ORDER BY id will return records as in array...

Comment: you are messing data? It looks like you are shuffling. This is not sorting. what are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes and ORDER BY value will return the way you want

Comment: please share sample data, expected output and the query which produces this issue.

Comment: MySQL has no notion of arrays, so your question is quite unclear.

Comment: I should clarify that I use PHP. I have $_POST array of values from user and need to reorder records in DB.

Comment: Simply sort according to user's input. Do not alter data.

Comment: This is admin action. I need exactly alter table so that ORDER BY id return records in order of this array

Comment: You're not making any sense. If you want to ORDER BY id, order by id. If you want to ORDER BY value, order by value.

Comment: I need an UPDATE query to replace records ID-s in order of array

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the values as a list to the query, you can use `field()`:

```
select *
from mytable 
where value in ('BMW', 'Audi', 'Opel')
order by field(value, 'BMW', 'Audi', 'Opel')
```

If you are giving a comma separated string, then use `find_in_set()`:

```
select *
from mytable 
where find_in_set(value, 'BMW, Audi, Opel')
order by find_in_set(value, 'BMW, Audi, Opel')
```

Comment: I just code an admin-panel. I have jquery-UI sortable list. Admin can drag records in necessary order and send form. $_POST array contains values in new order.
Now I need an UPDATE query to replace records ID-s in order of array...